# Select dentro de un from en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Intentare explicar lo que estoy tratando de obtener.

Tengo una tabla que se llama `GSCF300` en ella estan todos los datos de un cliente, como su numero de cuenta, su nombre, su id, entro otros.

Tengo otra tabla que se llama `GSCF305` en ella estan todos los saldos de un cliente, la tabla `GSCF300` se le relaciona con la `GSCF305` por el `id` unico del cliente (el campo termina con ...UUID).

El objetivo de relacionar la tabla 300 (referencia a la `GSCF300`) con la tabla 305 (referencia a la `GSCF305`) es lograr obtener el ultimo saldo a la fecha por numero de cuenta. Es decir,  si la cuenta registra dos saldos, el dia `09-05-19` y el dia `15-05-19` (por poner un ejemplo), necesito que me devuelva el del dia `15`.

Con el siguiente query, me trae todos los numeros de cuentas que necesito:

```
SELECT DISTINCT G300.G300CTA AS CUENTA FROM GSCF300 G300, GSCF305 G305 
        WHERE G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID AND G300.G300TCTA = 'V'
```

Y para obtener los ultimos saldos de las cuenta que me devuelve, hice el siguiente query, que el problema es para que me traiga los saldos tengo que especificarle que numero de cuenta es, sino me devuelve vacio.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO 
    FROM GSCF300 G300, GSCF305 G305
    WHERE G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
    AND G300.G300CTA = 1114244294 
    GROUP BY G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
    ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Los dos querys anteriores, los he tratado de unir, teniendo como resultado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT

tabla300.CUENTA,
tabla305.SALDO

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT G300.G300CTA AS CUENTA, G300.G300UUID AS ID FROM GSCF300 G300, GSCF305 G305 
        WHERE G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID AND G300.G300TCTA = 'V'  ) tabla300,

     (SELECT SALDO, ID, CUENTA FROM ( SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO, G305.G301UUID AS ID, G300.G300CTA AS CUENTA FROM GSCF300 G300, GSCF305 G305
                        WHERE G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
                        ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC ) 
                        WHERE ROWNUM <= 1) tabla305 

WHERE tabla300.ID = tabla305.ID
```

Y el resultado que devuelve es `NULL`, ya que nunca le especifico al query de saldos que numero de cuenta necesita verificar.

No se como podria usar los numeros de cuenta del primer query e incluirlos en el segundo.

(Disculpen el nombre de las tablas, ya estaban asi cuando llegue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo de manera sencilla utilizando la función analítica [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) ordenada por fecha de manera descendente, de manera que determinar cuál es la fila que corresponde a la última fecha se reduce a aquellas filas que devuelvan el número `1`. Finalmente filtrar con un `where` para incluir solamente la fila que interesa para cada cuenta.

La primera operación podemos realizarla dentro de un CTE, para que la consulta sea más legible y fácil de mantener.

La consulta, por ejemplo, para ver los *saldos actuales* de todas las cuentas de tipo `'V'` podría ser algo como la siguiente:

```
with
Base as (
select   G300.G300CTA as CUENTA
       , G305.G305S01 as SALDO
       , G305.G305FDIA as FECHA
       , row_number() over (partition by G300.G300CTA order by G305.G305FDIA desc) NumFila
  from GSCF305 G305
       inner join GSCF300 G300 on G300.G300UUID = G305.G300UUID
 where G300.G300TCTA = 'V'
)
select   a.CUENTA
       , a.SALDO
  from Base a
 where a.NumFila = 1;
```

A partir de allí, puedes filtrar con un `where` para ver el saldo de una cuenta en particular.

Es cierto que puede haber consultas más eficientes, pero tiendo a favorecer la mantenibilidad del software, y utilizando este enfoque puedes tener la misma consulta para todas las cuentas que para una sola. En mi opinión, la optimización vendría ya si el volumen de datos u otro factor particular lo demandan.

Comment: Sinceramente, muchas gracias, tenia meses intentado lograr ese resultado

Comment: Es un gusto. No dejes de ver otras funciones analíticas, esas son la mera onda. Un saludo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo un ejemplo como lo haría:

```
SELECT
G300.G300CTA as cuenta,
G305.G305S01 as saldo,
G305.G305FDIA as "Ultima transaccion"
FROM GSCF300 G300, GSCF305 G305
WHERE G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
AND G300.G300TCTA = 'V'
AND G305.G305FDIA = 
                   (SELECT max(G305FDIA)
                    FROM GSCF305 
                    WHERE G301UUID = G305.G301UUID);
```

Consulta con join:

```
SELECT 
G300.G300CTA as cuenta,
G305.G305S01 as saldo,
G305.G305FDIA as "Ultima transaccion"
FROM GSCF305 G305
JOIN GSCF300 G300
ON G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
WHERE G300.G300TCTA = 'V'
AND G305.G305FDIA = 
                   (SELECT max(G305FDIA)
                    FROM GSCF305 
                    WHERE G301UUID = G305.G301UUID);
```